# findViewById returns null in android 4.4.4 only

Tags: android, android-framelayout, findviewbyid

I used findViewById() in Android 4.4.4 / 4.4.2 / 5.0.2 .

But 4.4.4 only has error 'NullpointException'.

This is my code in MainActivity.

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(Util.StringToResourceID(this, "id", "main_map_fl"));
```

All android has no error, but only returns null in 4.4.4.

**However,**

```
Util.StringToResourceID(this, "id", "main_map_fl")
```

**It returns value.** Not null.

I tried setContentView before that code.

I tried clean project first, too.

I don't know why the error caused. Please help me.

+)

**Here is my .xml code that has 'main_map_fl'.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_rl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/main_tbt_ll"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    layout="@layout/layout_sub_tbt"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_map_fl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_tbt_ll"
    android:background="#ffff0000" >
</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_tbt_shadow_iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_tbt_ll"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_w" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_action_ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/main_action_set_admin_tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#b2333333"
        style="@style/font_31p_255_255_255"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_bg" >
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_actionbar_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_action_back_ib"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/> ...... 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

++)

**Util.StringToResourceID**

It is packagename and class String to int, I think.

```
public static int StringToResourceID(Context context, String _class, String _field) {
    int rval = 0;
    String a = context.getPackageName() + ".R$" + _class;

    try {
        Class Ra = Class.forName(a);

        try {
            rval = Ra.getField(_field).getInt(Ra);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException var7) {
            ...........
    return rval;
}
```

Comment: and what is… Util.StringToResourceID

Comment: I edited my quenstion! @MartinMarconcini

Comment: Well, what number is returned? Go look at R.java and find it

Comment: '2131427848' is returned. How can I find? There are '0x7f0b..' like this in R.java. @cricket_007

Comment: I'm sure you'll find lots of decimal to hexadecimal converters online

Comment: Thanks. I found it in R.java. There is, of course. ... @cricket_007

Comment: Alright, do you have only one res/layout folder? Not a values-21 one, for example?

Comment: I have many folders. And there are separated by resolution. I think I don't have layout folder that matched my tab. !!  @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, and are each of those API versions you're running using the same resolution?

Comment: Yes. API version are 19 in 4.4.2 and 4.4.4. And 5.0.2 is 21. @cricket_007

Comment: Those aren't resolutions

Comment: My point here is that you have some layout file that is being loaded differently, and the resource you're searching for is not part of it

Comment: Yes. you are right! but how can i know what resource i use in many resources? @cricket_007

Comment: There's only one value in R.java, and it's recreated when you clear the app. So, if you remove it from all the XML, then you rebuild the app, then ensure all relevant XML files have that resource ID (check your typos), then shouldn't crash

Comment: Does it work if you just call `findViewById(R.id.main_map_fl)` ? I don't really see the point of the `StringToResourceID()` method here.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to get the resourceId based on name, is that correct? How about this?

```
public static int StringToResourceID(Context context, String _class, String _field) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(_field, _class, context.getPackageName());
}
```